# Moving clustered data from HDFS to Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, mahout, k-means

I have been experimenting with Mahout in the Cloudera demo VM and have successfully clustered the sample synthetic control data (https://cwiki.apache.org/MAHOUT/clustering-of-synthetic-control-data.html) using the k-Means algorithm. I have used ClusterDumper and can view the Mahout output, but now I want to put the output into a Hive table. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct integration. Your best bet is to modify ClusterDumper to produce some kind of textual representation that can be imported into Hive as tabular data.

Answer (score 0):

Create an external table in Hive, That should point to Mahout o/p path.